# Dynamically enable/disable select option based on writing on input box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want help me , I want function when input value in new-domain
disable  domain and private list . also when input value in new-private
disable private list.

```
<h4>domain finder</h4>
<form action="test.php" method="POST">
    <select class="step1" name="domain">
        <option value="">Select a general domain</option>
    </select>
    <select class="step2" name="private">
        <option value="">Select a private area</option>
    </select>
    <label for="new-domain">other general domain</label>
    <input type="text" name="new-domain"></input>
    <label for="new-private">other private area</label>
    <input type="text" name="new-private"></input>
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you are asking for. Just to sum up:

1. When there is any input in the `new-domain` input field you want to disable both of the select elements.
2. When there is an input in the `new-private` field you only want to disable the private list.

If this is correct I have set up a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sm6jm7jr/) for you!

```js
$(function() {
 $('#new-domain').on('keyup', function() {
   // Disable both select elements.
    var inputLength = $(this).val().length;
    var $elements = $('.step1, .step2');
    
    if (inputLength > 0) {
     disableSelectElements($elements, true)
    } else {
     disableSelectElements($elements, false)
    }
  });
  
  $('#new-private').on('keyup', function() {
   // Disable just the private list.
    var inputLength = $(this).val().length;
    var $elements = $('.step2');
    
    if (inputLength > 0) {
     disableSelectElements($elements, true)
    } else {
     disableSelectElements($elements, false)
    }
  });
})

var disableSelectElements = function($elements, onOrOff) {
 $elements.prop('disabled', onOrOff);
};
```

```html
<h4>domain finder</h4>
<form action="test.php" method="POST">
    <select class="step1" name="domain">
        <option value="">Select a general domain</option>
    </select>
    <select class="step2" name="private">
        <option value="">Select a private area</option>
    </select>
    <label for="new-domain">other general domain</label>
    <input type="text" name="new-domain" id="new-domain" />
    <label for="new-private">other private area</label>
    <input type="text" name="new-private" id="new-private" />
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Essentially what I am doing is attaching listeners for a successful keypress input into both of those input fields and disabling or reenabling the input fields as necessary. I check for the length to make sure there is actually something in the text box (in case someone types a letter and then deletes it) and respond accordingly.

This function can definitely be improved with some better handling of all the various inputs and scenarios that you might encounter in the wild, but if it's for an internal tool or prototype this should get the job done.

Comment: thank you, so much.
Yes, you understand very well what I want

Comment: I have another problem , I hope help to solve it in these link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37006364/two-dynamic-lists-related-to-each-other

Comment: @A.fahad if this answer works for you, can you please select it as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the on("input") from jquery?

```
$('DOMELEMENT').on('input', function() {
    $(this).checkvalue --> disable/enable.
});
```

Pretty sure this works, if not keep googling for jquery on text input change, good luck.